# How to live stream camera footage from solo drone during flight?

Tags: java, android, camera, 3dr

I am trying to access my Pixpro sp360 4k camera while it is attached to a 3dr drone during flight and send the live feed from the Camera to YouTube.

I tried using drone-kit provided by 3dr to access the camera. It works, but when I try to send that data to YouTube I don't have access to Internet or Mobile Data because I have to connect to the drone's controller via WiFi, and it does not have Internet access.

I want to be able to access the camera without being directly connected to it, so I can live to stream the live feed to YouTube.

I have also tried using the application provided by Pixpro to try and access the camera, but it force closes every time that I connect to the camera's WiFi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re misunderstanding the capabilities of the drone.

To stream footage it uses long range wifi. This is a LAN connection of sorts and not a connection to the ‘outside world’. The connection exists only to those connected to the network with no external interface.

Streaming directly from the drone ‘live’ is not possible. You’d need to connect your drone to a middleware that routes its data through to a live internet connection which then has software setup to stream as you’re describing.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. Do you happen to have any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.dji.com/au/lightbridge-2 something like this may work with your model. Check the manufacturer of the drone for similar products.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look.